# How do you make a div 100% - some px?

Tags: css

I have two divs. I want the one on the left to be 200px. I want the one on the right to fill up whatever the screen width is - 200px. In other words the div on the right should be 100% of the available space after the div on the left is drawn. Is there a pure css way of doing this?

[rough example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugp5e/)

```
<div class='l'></div><div class='r'></div>
.l {
    display:inline-block;
    background:green;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}

.r {
    background:red;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UrubG/

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVBwa/)**

Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="fixed">Fixed Width</div>
<div id="flexible">Flexible Width</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
#fixed {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#flexible {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: green;
}
```